# sql group by time periods 10 mins

Tags: sql

I would like to change the time periods from '1 hour' to '10 mins'.

and change the display time from '10' to '10:00'

```
declare @periodStart datetime
declare @periodEnd datetime

set @periodStart =  CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE() - 1, 120)
set @periodEnd = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE() , 120) 

set @periodStart = dateadd(HH, datepart(HH,@periodStart), convert(varchar(12),@periodStart,112))
set @periodEnd = dateadd(HH, datepart(HH,@periodEnd), convert(varchar(12),@periodEnd,112))


;with dh
as
(
select top 144 
DATEADD(HOUR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Object_id])-1,convert(varchar(12),@periodStart,112)) as HoDstart,
DATEADD(HOUR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Object_id]),convert(varchar(12),@periodStart,112)) as HoDend,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Object_id)-1 as DayHour  
from sys.columns 
)
select d.DayHour, count(f.Hostname) as 'Counter'
from dh d  
left join FileBackup f
on    f.StartTime < d.HoDend 
and f.EndTime >= d.HoDstart  
where d.HoDstart between @periodStart and @periodEnd
group by d.DayHour
order by d.DayHour
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post..

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17976.t-sql-group-by-time-interval.aspx

I think the group by 1/6 th of the hour - every sixth of the hour would be every 10 minutes.

Re-writing the query, we should see from the last answer:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(minute, logtime)/6 AS [SixthHour],
           COUNT(loginid) AS [Logins Completed]
FROM    somelog
GROUP BY DATEPART(minute, logtime)/6
```

This should help - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f60f3/1

Comment: Sorry about I can't do it.....http://imagesup.net/?di=11138120186212   http://imagesup.net/?di=913812018632

Answer (score 0):

with the wanted label etc, based on the minutes/6 example by Leptonator

```
DECLARE @periodStart datetime
DECLARE @periodEnd datetime

SET @periodStart = dateadd(DAY, datediff(DAY,0, GETDATE()), -1)
SET @periodEnd   = dateadd(DAY, datediff(DAY,0, GETDATE()), 0)

SELECT
        convert(varchar(5),dateadd(MINUTE,number*10,'00:00:00'),8) AS label
      , x.Logins_Completed
FROM master..spt_values AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                     DATEPART(MINUTE, logtime)/6 AS [SixthHour]
                   , COUNT(loginid) AS [Logins_Completed]
            FROM    somelog
            WHERE ( logtime >= @periodStart AND logtime < @periodEnd )
            GROUP BY DATEPART(MINUTE, logtime)/6
          ) AS x ON t1.number = x.SixthHour
WHERE t1.type = 'P'
AND t1.number between 0 and 143;
```

see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ed4d/2)

extra observations:

Not sure why you are setting the date parameters twice:
both of the following result in the same values for both parameters as your existing:

```
/* easier to read */
declare @periodStart datetime
declare @periodEnd datetime

set @periodStart = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE() - 1, 120)
set @periodEnd   = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE() , 120) 

select 
      @periodStart
    , @periodEnd
;

/* faster */
declare @periodStart datetime
declare @periodEnd datetime

set @periodStart = dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, GETDATE()), -1)
set @periodEnd   = dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, GETDATE()), 0)

select 
      @periodStart
    , @periodEnd
;
```

Additionally you might want to reconsider using 'between' as the date rage selection method:

```
where ( d.HoDstart >= @periodStart and d.HoDstart < @periodEnd )
```

see: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)